# C++ How do i check i got an active connection to certain site

Tags: c++

C++ How do i check i got an active connection to certain site

Basically my mini project require connection to the site somesite.com

I want to upon launching my application, do a test to see if I can fetch data from somesite.com , if fetch.fail(), it will echo fail to establish connection to somesite.com

How can i do this.

Thanks for all the help !

Answer (score 3):

C++ have no networking support in standard library. So you should use so third-party library to do it. Or you can make it by means of OS function calls.

I think the simplest one is to use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).
[There](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html) is example that you need.